# Duplicate product with some values changed, Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to duplicate a product, but there I want to change some values like: title, url, description and some attributes from a plugin. At the moment I have some code that duplicates a product.

```
$wc_adp = new WC_Admin_Duplicate_Product;
$dproduct = $wc_adp->product_duplicate( wc_get_product(44) );
```